# Redirect to subdomain based on the input using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need your help with my .htaccess file. 
What im trying to do is to redirect the url which was sent by the user to a subdomain with the **same** path.

for example:
`mydomain.net/rankings.php` or `mydomain.net/rankings`

should result in: 
`subdomain.mydomain.net/rankings.php`

Furthermore the decision which subdomain should be used is based on the stored cookies.
In order to do this I created an index.php file into the main folder '/' which will check the cookies of an user and also redirect based on the giving url using php-parameters which will be sent using index.php?site=rankings.php.

So eventually I need to redirect the giving url input to index.php and add the url-path using php-parameters. 
Like this:

`mydomain.net/rankings` should be redirected or rewritten to 
`mydomain.net/index.php?site=rankings.php`

The whole internet is full of .htacces rewrites to change php-parameters into good looking url-paths but I need it the other way around.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1.php [L,QSA]
```

If you want redirect use `[L,QSA,R]` flags.